# Drawing Sprites with button click - Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Would it be good idea to create(draw on the screen) sprite when user click on the one of the buttons? The sprite would be created before and user would only "initialise" it by drawing it to the screen. 
Unfortunately the code I have got at the moment does not work, it prints "Start" but does not draw sprite. what could be the reason for that?

Code:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if button.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)
                print ("Start")
```

Answer (score 1):

Examples:

```
blit_player = False

while True:

     # ....

     if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
         if button.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
             blit_player = True
             print ("Start")

     # ....

     if blit_player:
         screen.blit(player.image, player.rect.topleft)

     pygame.display.update
```

or - if you whan to add more sprites:

```
blited_sprites = []

while True:

     # ....

     if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
         if button.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
             blited_sprites.append( player )
             print ("Start")

     # ....

     for x in blited_sprites:
         screen.blit(x.image, x.rect.topleft)

     pygame.display.update
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't show up because you have a main loop updating the screen a certain number of times every second. If you want the sprite to show up, you'll have to blit it every time you update the screen.

Comment: This is actually pretty normal. I think you'll find it a lot more useful when you want to make a sprite do things like animate or move around. The other answer posted has some more complete code you can look at.